# Usando Python para Extração de Equações, Figuras e Outros Itens de Arquivo LaTeX

Tags: python, latex

Estou em um projeto pessoal que envolve deixar um artigo escrito em *LaTeX* o mais limpo possível para envio a tradução.

Visando aumentar minha produtividade, evitar problemas de vazamento de informação e facilitar para o tradutor, que não tem muita familiaridade com este tipo de escrita, resolvi que enviaria o texto original mais "limpo", sem as equações por exemplo. Depois posso estender o mesmo conceito para figuras, etc.

**Problema**: Depois de extraído o que se deseja (equações por exemplo), dois novos arquivos são salvos, um contendo somente as equações e outro limpo, sem as equações. Cheguei a montar o código abaixo, que já funciona.
O desafio é: (1) A cada extração, deve ser deixado uma referência para retornar a mesma equação no mesmo lugar que estava, quando recebido o texto traduzido;
(2) Para retornar as equações originais, deve existir outro script para este fim.

**Alguma sugestão de estratégia para melhor tratar deste desafio ?**

Segue o código atual funcionando, sem ainda contudo atender os itens (1) e (2) acima.

```
print('Inicio do Script')
infileName = open('document.tex','r')
inOrig = infileName.readlines()
outfileName_eq = open('document_equacoes.tex','w')
outfileName_tex = open('document_limpo.tex','w')
extract_block = False
oneWrite = False
lista = [['begin{equation}', 'end{equation}'],\
         ['begin{equation*}', 'end{equation*}'],\
         ['begin{eqnarray}', 'end{eqnarray}'],\
         ['begin{eqnarray*}', 'end{eqnarray*}'],\
         ['begin{align}', 'end{align}'],\
         ['begin{align*}', 'end{align*}']]
for list in lista:
    print('Examinando '+ list[0] + ' e ', list[1])
    for line in inOrig:
        if list[0] in line:
            extract_block = True
        if extract_block:
            outfileName_eq.write(line)
        if list[1] in line:
            extract_block = False
            outfileName_eq.write("%------------------------------------------\n\n")

#separado para melhor entendimento do funcionamento    
for line in inOrig:
    for list in lista:
        if list[0] in line:
            extract_block = True            
            oneWrite = True
        if list[1] in line:
            extract_block = False
            oneWrite = True
    if not (extract_block or oneWrite):
        outfileName_tex.write(line)
        oneWrite = True
    oneWrite = False

infileName.close()
outfileName_eq.close()
outfileName_tex.close()
print('Fim do Script')
```

O documento em LaTeX que usei para teste é o seguinte, que para combinar com o código acima, deve ser salvo como "document.tex"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Disponibiliza acentos.
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\title{Titulo do Artigo}
\author{Nome do Autor}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
    \section{Primeira Seção}
    \lipsum[2-4]
\section[Exemplo de Fórmula]{Fórmula}
Neste trecho existe um exemplo de como aparece geralmente 
uma equação. A primeira equação é a de Báskara, conforme (\ref{eq:bask01})
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
    \label{eq:bask01}
\end{equation}
Outra forma de expressar as fórmulas que também precisam ser verificadas abaixo
\begin{eqnarray*}
    x =& a^b\\
    y =& h^{\pi.r}
\end{eqnarray*}
A seguinte é muito parecida com a de Báskara e pode ser visto em (\ref{eq:bask02}), no entanto não existe em literatura.
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{-b/2 \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2acb}
    \label{eq:bask02}
\end{equation}
Outra forma de expressar as fórmulas que também precisam ser verificada
\begin{eqnarray}
    x &=& a^b\\
    y &=& h^{\pi.r}
\end{eqnarray}
Finalmente outro método com $k_2$ tal como (\ref{eq:seqEq})
\begin{align}
    k_1&= s^2\\
    k_2&= k^2 \label{eq:seqEq}
\end{align}
Fim das descrições gerais
\end{document}
```

Comment: Você tem a _string_ da equação, certo? Crie um _hash_ MD5 (biblioteca `hashlib`) e monte um dicionário onde a chave é o _hash_ e o conteúdo é o texto da _string_. Este dicionário você pode salvar em disco como um arquivo JSON (biblioteca `json`), no lugar onde a equação estava você deixa um comentário do LaTex contendo apenas o _hash_.

Comment: Parece ser uma boa solução. Pensei também em uma _tag_. Via MD5 parece ser melhor ainda, pois não me preocupo em "inventar" uma diferente para cada elementos que estou querendo extrair. Terei que testar. Não estou muito familiarizado com o JSON, mas acredito que será melhor, por ser estruturado. Grato pela dica.

Comment: A chave MD5 vai te ajudar até a identificar as equações idênticas e usando a tag de comentário do LaTeX, além de ser mais fácil de identificar, você não quebra a compilação do documento. Trabalhe com o dicionários e use as funções `json.load()` para carregá-lo de disco e `json.dump()` para salvá-lo.